# Unable to send base64 > 600kb via php post

Tags: php, post, base64, content-length

I am trying to send images (base64) to my backend via php post. Images smaller than 600kb work just fine but images above 600kb result in an empty post value.

These are my php.ini stats

```
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
memory_limit = 64M
```

content_length of 2.33M results in a fail
when the content_length is somewhere around 0.20M does what it is supposed to do

Does anybody know how i can upload images larger than 600kb?

Comment: are you sure you modified the right .ini file? what does `phpinfo()` show as the effective values if you execute it in your post handling script?

Comment: I don't know if you checked the size of the file before or after base64 encoding, but files encoded with base64 will be around 33% larger than before encoding.

Comment: @Chris +33% == 900Kb. This Should fit any limits. (Also with default php.ini)

Comment: Do you see error messages in the log file? If yes, can you post them?

Comment: My hosting provider does not let me change the php.ini, i got these stats with `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize')`.
I do not get any error messages however, i do get a warning about Register_long_arrays but this should not matter should it?